# Swift UITextFieldBeganEditing to select all text did not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I try to select all text when I tap the textfield, and I try to get the text position and invoke the textField.selectedTextRange method to select the text. It works when I tap the left part of the textField, but not the right part. When I tap the right part, the text just aligned but not selected. Why would that happen?

And here is the issue I recorded as a gif:

[display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZN6k.gif)

Below is the code in the textFieldDidBeginEditing method :

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        textField.textAlignment = .left
        self.trailingOfTextField.constant = 80

        let endPosition = textField.endOfDocument

        let startP = textField.position(from: endPosition, offset: 0)
        let endP = textField.position(from: endPosition, offset: -textField.text!.count)

        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: startP!, to: endP!)

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with you clicking on the left or right side of the text. It has to do with the ordering of your clicks and the state of the `selectedTextRange` when those clicks occurred.

What you need to do is reset the `selectedTextRange` when you dismiss the keyboard so it goes back in its initial state.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.delegate = self
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(
            from: textField.beginningOfDocument,
            to: textField.endOfDocument
        )
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.selectedTextRange = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I use your code and run it on iOS13.4 and it's still not working, However, when I change the simulator's iOS version to iOS13.3, everything works fine~even my original code works...so I think it might be a iOS13.4 version issue...But I still don't know how to fix it on iOS13.4, maybe I need to wait for next version...

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear selectedTextRange on textFieldDidEndEditing

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
  textField.selectedTextRange = nil
}
```

Preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QxBy.jpg

The complete code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    textField.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap)))
  }

  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    textField.textAlignment = .left

    let endPosition = textField.endOfDocument

    let startP = textField.position(from: endPosition, offset: 0)
    let endP = textField.position(from: endPosition, offset: -textField.text!.count)

    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: startP!, to: endP!)
  }

  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.selectedTextRange = nil
  }

  @objc func didTap() {
    view.endEditing(true)
    textField.textAlignment = .center
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I use your code and run it on iOS13.4 and it's still not working, the same problem occurs. But I noticed your link to imgur.com and the iOS version is iOS13.3, so I change my simulator to it and everything works fine...so it might be a iOS version issue..